# Is it efficient to use LINQ to parse strings?

Tags: vb.net, string, linq

I've been using LINQ so much in the last couple of weeks that when I had to write a one line function to remove < and > from a string, I found that I had written it as a LINQ query:

```
Public Function StripLTGT(text As String) As String
    Return String.Join("", (From i As Char In text.ToCharArray Where i <> "<"c Where i <> ">"c).ToArray)
End Function
```

My question is, is it better to do it with LINQ as above or with StringBuilder as I've always done, as below:

```
Public Function StripLTGT(text As String) As String
    Dim a As New StringBuilder(text)
    a = a.Replace("<", "")
    a = a.Replace(">", "")
    Return a.ToString
End Function
```

Both work, the second one is easier to read, but the first one is designed for executing queries against arrays and other enumerables.

Comment: which one is more readable....

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Replace("[<>]", "")
```

Is much more straightforward.

Or:

```
myString = myString.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "")
```

Whether or not option A, B or C is faster than the others is hard to say because option A may be better on small strings while option B may be better on long strings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Either one should really be fine in terms of functionality. The first one is *not* efficient as is. The `ToArray` call is doing *far* more work than necessary (if you're on .NET 4.0, it is not needed anyway), and the `ToCharArray` call is not needed. Basically the characters in the input string are being iterated a lot more than they need to be, and extra arrays are allocated superfluously.

I wouldn't say this particularly *matters*; but you asked about efficiency, so that's why I mention it.

The second one seems fine to me. Note that if you wanted to go the one-line route, you could still do so with a `StringBuilder` and I *think* still have something more concise than the LINQ version (though I haven't counted characters). Whether or not this even outperforms the more direct `String.Replace` option is kind of unclear to me, though:

```
' StringBuilder.Replace version:
Return New StringBuilder(text).Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").ToString()

' String.Replace version:
Return text.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "")
```